# How do X clients know that they will need to connect to TCP port 6000+<display number>?

Tags: x11, xforwarding

When I request X forwarding from SSH server, then SSH server sets a `$DISPLAY` variable with value `localhost:10.0`. In addition, it starts to listen on `127.0.0.1` port `6010`(and also `::1` port `6010` for IPv6):

```
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                     Local Address:Port                                                      Peer Address:Port                
LISTEN     0      128                                               127.0.0.1:6010                                                                    *:*                     users:(("sshd",pid=11405,fd=10))
```

How do X clients know that they will need to connect to TCP port 6010? Does this work in a way that by default they connect to TCP port `6000`+`<display number>` and as display number is in this example 10, then they will connect to TCP port `6010`?

Comment: A term that might be helpful is *well-known port*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It’s part of the [X11 protocol](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html) (search for "6000") and is documented *e.g.* in [`Xorg(1)`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xorg.1.html):

> **Xorg** listens on port 6000+*n*, where *n* is the display number. This connection type can be disabled with the `-nolisten` option (see the [`Xserver(1)`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/Xserver.1.html) man page for details).

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

Just as browsers know to connect to a webserver on port 80 (unless otherwise specified), X clients know to talk to X servers on port 6000 + display number (unless otherwise specified).

These expectations are what *standards* (and, more broadly, documentation) give us — else, interaction between computers would be extremely cumbersome.

Comment: I can make an educated guess whom your pointed comment is aimed at, but it could look like you are having a go at the questioner, which (if my guess is correct) is not the case at all.  It is best to make that clear.

Comment: @JdeBP: Eh? What "pointed comment"? Where am I "having a go" at anyone?? I'm very simply answering the question...

Comment: Your pointed comment about standards, of course.

Comment: @JdeBP: I think you must be misreading it, because I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. That web browsers should talk to webservers on port 80 is given by as close to a standard as there is: the RFC(s) on HTTP. Similar "legislation" is passed for all other protocols. That's how networks are defined. Similarly, that's how X clients "know" which ports to use, which was the question posted above. What's "pointed" about that?