# Why does netstat show my socket tutorial program having a port of "x11-1" instead of the port I set in code?

Tags: c, tcp, socket, port

I am trying to learn about socket programming, and I have the following function to set up a socket:

```
  29 int CreatePassiveSock(char *protocol, char *portstr, int qlen) {                         
  30   int s, port, type, saddrlen;                                                           
  31   char *endptr;                                                                          
  32   struct sockaddr_in saddr;                                                              
  33   port = (int) strtol(portstr, &endptr, 10);                                             
  34   if (*endptr) {                                                                         
  35     printf("\nPlease specify a positive integer for port\n");                            
  36     exit(1);                                                                             
  37   }                                                                                      
  38   saddrlen = sizeof(saddr);                                                              
  39   memset(&saddr, 0, saddrlen);                                                           
  40   saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                                                            
  41   saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                                                    
  42   saddr.sin_port = htons(port);                                                          
  43   if (strcmp("tcp", protocol) == 0)                                                      
  44     type = SOCK_STREAM;                                                                  
  45   else if (strcmp("udp", protocol) == 0)                                                 
  46     type = SOCK_DGRAM;                                                                   
  47   else {                                                                                 
  48     printf("Unsupported protocol given");                                                
  49     exit(1);                                                                             
  50   }                                                                                      
  51   if ((s = socket(PF_INET, type, 0)) == -1){                                             
  52     perror("socket call failed");                                                        
  53     exit(1);                                                                             
  54   }                                                                                      
  55   if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, saddrlen) == -1) {                              
  56     perror("Bind failed");                                                               
  57     exit(1);                                                                             
  58   }                                                                                      
  59   if (type == SOCK_STREAM) {                                                             
  60     if (listen(s, qlen) == -1) {                                                         
  61       perror("listen failed");                                                           
  62       exit(1);                                                                           
  63     }                                                                                    
  64   }                                                                                      
  65   return s;                                                                              
  66 }
```

When I call this with 6001 as port number, this is the line that shows up with `netstat -a | head`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:x11-1           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Why would it show up as 0.0.0.0:x11-1? Shouldn't I get 0.0.0.0:6001?

If it matters I am doing this on a laptop running PopOS.

Answer (score 2):

TCP port 6001 is identified as `x11-1` in `/etc/services`, so `netstat` shows it using that label: in a similar fashion to the way it looks up host names corresponding to the IP addresses it finds, it looks up service names corresponding to the port numbers it finds. See [`man 5 services`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) for a description of `/etc/services` and the functions used to access it, [How do X clients know that they will need to connect to TCP port 6000+<display number>?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333969/86440) for an explanation of 6000+ range port number mapping.

You can examine `/etc/services` to see which services are known on your system; [the official registry is maintained by the IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), and you can find [the X11 assignments there too](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=x11).

You can force `netstat` to show you the port number using `-n`.

Comment: Do you know where I could read about which ports might have string identifiers? As in, how does netstat know to display x11-1 instead of just 6001? Is there an authoritative document that says it should do this or netstat just does this because x11 is common and doing so is convenient? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `netstat` knows to display `x11-1` because [`/etc/services`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) tells it that TCP port 6001 maps to that service. If you look at that file on your system you’ll see what names are known. See the link above or `man 5 services` locally for details.